# Docker stack: publish port to host

Tags: docker, firewall, docker-swarm, docker-stack

### the question

When running `$ docker stack deploy ...`, is there any way to publish a port in a way that it's **only** accessible to the host-machine?

I'm  using a Ubuntu server instance running at Digital-Ocean at the moment.

### example

let's say I run a **mysql** service named **db**. I can access the database from a different container *without* the need for having `ports: ["3306:3306"]` in my `docker-compose.yml` file. From my other container I can just use **db** as mysql host and the default port. This works as intended.

Now I want to access the database from my host machine. As far as I know this isn't possible without publishing a port. When I put `ports: ["3306:3306"]` in my `docker-compose.yml` file I can access the database using `mysql -uroot -p -h 127.0.0.1`. The problem, is that the database is now externally accessible as well, I can log in to the database from any PC using `mysql -uroot -p -h foo.com`, this seems unnecessary unsafe.

I can think of a few other use-cases where you might need this:

- The use of any database that needs to be accessed by a docker container, and **also** from an app outside of docker.
- Using nginx, not running in docker, as a reverse proxy for an app that *is* running in docker. Without exposing the app itself to the web

If these use-cases can be solved using some other solution I'd be happy to hear of course.

### Some of the things I've tried

- using a firewall to block the access to port 3306. This didn't work because docker messes with the ip-tables.
- using `ports: ["127.0.0.1:3306:3306"]` in the compose file. This works as intended when user `docker-compose up`. unfortunately this doesn't work when using Docker stack.
- A lot of other possible solutions that didn't lead anywhere...

Comment: Are your hosts on AWS or similar?

Comment: I'm hosting on Digital-Ocean at the moment

Comment: Well I guess you could publish the ports but control the access via the Digital ocean firewalls (if they have something like AWS security groups). I do something similar on AWS where our containers publish to the box but the Access control is done by our AWS security groups.That way we can access DB console from external if required but the apps still use internal.